# Allocating memory for multiple images in cuda to calculate their mean image

Tags: cuda

I want to calculate the mean image from the dataset of images(around 100). All the images are 2 dimensional. Can i go for cudaMalloc3D inbuilt function or is their any other way to allocate memory..

Answer (score 1):

I often treat multidimensional array as 1D array in cuda. Let's say, you want to allocate 3D array of size (`NxMxK`). Then, with the `cudaMalloc` command, you can allocate 1D array `a` of size (`N*M*K`). In order to access element with indexes `[i][j][k]`, you just call `a[i+j*N+k*N*M]` (assuming 0-based indexing, column-major ordering).

This is also a way to index threads in multidimensional blocks (you can have 1D,2D or 3D blocks):
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#thread-hierarchy